# Formating issue with RStudio and dplyr, while capturing output

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I face an encoding issue with the latest version of RStudio when I try to capture the output.

If I define a tibble and print it, I obtain the expected result:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- tibble(test=c("Hello","World"))
print(x)
```

(The result is)

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  test  
  <chr>
1 Hello
2 World
```

But, within a shiny app, I need to capture the results as following:

```
txt <- capture.output(x, type = "output")
print(txt)
```

Here, I obtain:

```
[1] "\033[38;5;246m# A tibble: 2 x 1\033[39m"      "  tes  "                                     
[3] "  \033[3m\033[38;5;246m<chr>\033[39m\033[23m" "\033[38;5;250m1\033[39m Hello"               
[5] "\033[38;5;250m2\033[39m World"
```

I didn't get the issue with former versions of RStudio. I don't get it using R GUI.

RStudio version is:

```
$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.4.1106’

$release_name
[1] "Tiger Daylily"
```

R Session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.4.2      assertthat_0.2.1 utf8_1.2.1       crayon_1.4.1     R6_2.5.0         DBI_1.1.1       
 [7] lifecycle_1.0.0  magrittr_2.0.1   pillar_1.6.0     cli_2.4.0        rlang_0.4.10     rstudioapi_0.13 
[13] vctrs_0.3.7      generics_0.1.0   ellipsis_0.3.1   forcats_0.5.1    tools_4.0.5      glue_1.4.2      
[19] purrr_0.3.4      compiler_4.0.5   pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidyselect_1.1.0 tibble_3.1.0
```

Comment: Stéphane’s answer shows a way of disabling the output colouring. But a better solution would be not to use `capture.output`, and to instead use a more appropriate way of displaying tables in a Shiny application, e.g. via the ‘DT’ package or one of the many packages that render static HTML output from a table.

Comment: Thank you Konrad. I use `DT` to display nice tables in my Shiny application but this `capture.output` is really handy in this case to check what happens under the hood. (I catch some behaviors of the underlying code using regular `cat()` in my code, post-process the capture using `paste0(txt, "\n", collapse = "")` and then render it directly in the (development) app using `renderText`.)

Answer (score 1):

This is for colors and highlighting. You can disable with:

```
options(cli.num_colors=1)
```